# "Operation not supported" for setfacl inside a python script

Tags: linux, ssh, python, acl

I've programmed a script using python which logs in as `root` on the host machine and executes some commands. Therefore it uses `ssh`. I want to setup `acl`. If I do following commands in the command line, everything works well.

```
s.execute("setfacl -m user:www-data:r-x,mask:r-x /srv/gitosis/.ssh")
s.execute("setfacl -m user:www-data:r--,mask:r-- /srv/gitosis/.ssh/id_dsa")
```

This is the python call and I always get:

```
setfacl: /srv/gitosis/.ssh: Operation not supported
setfacl: /srv/gitosis/.ssh/id_dsa: Operation not supported
```

What is the problem here? Doing that via ssh directly works well.

Comment: What is `s`? What OS are you using? Is ACL enabled on the filesystem?

Comment: I'm using Debian 6.0.4. Yes `acl` is enabled. If I call the command directly via bash it works. `s` is my ssh handle inside python. On this handle I can write via `execute` on the command line.

Comment: When you say *when I do the following from the command line* are you logged onto the target machine?

Comment: yes - but also via ssh (from the same machine where I execute the python script).

Comment: Can you post how `s` is defined/opened?

Comment: I'm using following ssh-script, which is basically a wrapper of paramiko. http://media.commandline.org.uk//code/ssh.txt and paramiko: http://www.lag.net/paramiko/ I'm using standard port, and standard authentication via password.

Comment: Are you sure that ACLs are enabled *on the filesystem where `/srv/gitosis/.ssh` is located*? Please describe precisely what commands you run, with a short, complete Python script, and always starting from your client machine and including the ssh steps.

Comment: I found out the problem. During my installation script I'm doing a reboot. Afterwards I'm polling the target for connecting again. Python could connect to the target although it was just shutting down. The script executed the acl commands while shutting down and got this error. So problem solved :)